# How to get an integer value in a list if user inputs the corresponding string value?

Tags: python, list, input

I want the user to select a string value from a list and the quantity of that string they want.
Using those two factors, I want to multiply the the amount of the item they chose with the value of that item and add that to their balance.

```
import random
from math import fsum

item_val = {
"Common": 10,
"Uncommon": 25,
"Rare": 50,
"Epic": 100,
"Legendary": 250,
"Exotic": 500,
}

def item_trading():
    balance = []
    init_bal = random.randint(10, 500)
    balance.append(init_bal)
    print(f"Your starting balance is: {balance}. ")
    while True:
        which_item = input("Which item would you like to purchase?: ")
        which_item = str(which_item)
        if which_item not in item_val:
            print("That item doesn not exist. Please try again. ")
            continue
        else:
            print(f"You want to purchase {which_item} rarity of items. ")
            num_of_items = input(f"How many {which_item} items would you like to purchase?: ")
            num_of_items = int(num_of_items)
            print(f"You have purchased {num_of_items} {which_item} items! ")
            for rarity,val in item_val.items():
                balance.append(-(num_of_items)*(val))  
                print(f"You current balance is: {fsum(balance)} ")
                break
        break

item_trading()
```

However, "balance.append(-(num_of_items)*(val))" only uses the first value ("Common" value) which is 10, so even if the user selected a "Rare" value (50) it only multiplies by 10.
How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `str()` always returns a string, you don't need to use `str(which_item)`

Comment: Why are you looping through `item_val.items()`? You should just use `item_vals[which_item]`

Comment: If you put an unconditional `break` in a loop, it only iterates once, so you don't go through the whole dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar 
item_val[which_item]: throws TypeError: 'int' object not iterable
if you mean item_val[which_item](): it throws TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

i also am unsure of where i would place the break within the loop, I thought i already have one in there?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop over `item_vals.items()`, just use `item_vals[which_item]`

```
init_bal = random.randint(10, 500)
balance = [init_bal]

def item_trading():
    print(f"Your starting balance is: {balance}. ")
        which_item = input("Which item would you like to purchase?: ")
        which_item = str(which_item)
        if which_item not in item_val:
            print("That item doesn not exist. Please try again. ")
            continue
        print(f"You want to purchase {which_item} rarity of items. ")
        num_of_items = input(f"How many {which_item} items would you like to purchase?: ")
        num_of_items = int(num_of_items)
        print(f"You have purchased {num_of_items} {which_item} items! ")
        balance.append(-num_of_items * item_vals[which_item]
        print(f"Your current balance is: {fsum(balance)} "
        break

item_trading()
```

Also,  the initialization of the `balance` list should not be in the function. If it's in the function, you reset the balance every time you call the function, instead of keeping a running balance.